# Is it possible to download Tomahawk JAR file source code and make change in a class and recompile as JAR file?

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

In Tomahawk JAR file, we have a class MyFacesResourceLoader.java which have a method `_defineCaching()_` that creates headers to the js/css files, I want to modify default headers in the file, so is it possible to modify the source code of Tomahawk Jar file and recompile as Jar file. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to

> Is it possible to download Tomahawk JAR file source code and make change in a class and recompile as JAR file?

is:

Yes

Comment: Can you give some steps on how to do it? I'm new to building JAR files.

Comment: Uhhhmmmm you seriously want to change some fundamental code of an old library and do not know how to build a jar file? Use a search engine of your liking... e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=build+tomahawk+jsf+from+source

Comment: I have done it using the link mentioned below.


https://www.talksinfo.com/how-to-edit-class-file-from-a-jar/

Comment: But the JAR building process is painful. Had lot of issues to make a small change. So followed above link and it worked.

Comment: How is it painful?